# NHibernate offline mode

Tags: database, nhibernate

I have a question
Is there some way of doing this in NHibernate:
If the database is offline (connection error, or something else) to persist all the changes locally or somewhere else, and when the database comes online, resyncronize these two databases.

How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's outside the scope of NHibernate.

You could do it in a higher-level layer (an abstraction on top of Session that catches errors and saves somewhere else) or in a lower-level one (implementing an IDriver that hides the connection details).

Both are complicated. A better choice is to use a database with replication support (SqlServer is one example), always work with the local DB, and let the replication engine deal with synchronization.

Of course this has the added issue of conflict management (which happens in all of the patterns anyway)

Comment: what about MS Syncronization Framework. Can I use that with nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Diego that is out of NH scope. After that a solution could be use the Command Pattern to update the modify requests and enqueue each request in a trustable queue ( MSMQ for example ) and do the actual DB update at the end of this queue. When the client application is out of the NET the queue keep the modification that are flushed at soon the connection comes back.